# Fabric deploy to multiple hosts with custom parameters for each

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

I was looking a way to execute tasks on multiple servers (yes I'm aware of roledefs -R and hosts -H options) but I need some extra parameters like different user for each host etc and I wanted to keep it clean and tidy as I keep my host as functions definitions (as suggested on stack somewhere)to have possibility to execute task on just one like this

```
def test():
    user='root' 
    env.host='myapp-test.com'
```

I started with modifying env.tasks but it turned out they are iterated by generator and access to them through context_manager was only for view (as in fab docs).

I wanted to keep my "function-like hosts" so I ended up with modifying env.hosts dynamically and writing decorator which updates server-specific data depending on current env.host (will override default task decorator in future) working code below (I had to change names in code for security reasons hope didn't break any functionality):

```
APP_SERVERS= {
    'test':{
        'envname':'test',
        'user':'deploy_user',
        'host':'myapp-test.com',
        'host_string':'myapp-test.com',
        'path':'/opt/myapp/test/',
        'www_root':'http://myapp-test.com/',
        'retries_before_killing':3,
        'retry_sleep':2
    },
    'staging':{
        'envname':'staging',
        'user':'deploy_user',
        'host':'myapp-staging.com',
        'host_string':'myapp-staging.com',
        'path':'/opt/myapp/staging/',
        'www_root':'http://myapp-staging.com/',
        'retries_before_killing':3,
        'retry_sleep':2
    },
    'uat':{
        'envname':'uat',
        'user':'deploy_user',
        'host':'myapp-uat.com',
        'host_string':'myapp-uat.com',
        'path':'/opt/myapp/uat/',
        'www_root':'http://myapp-uat.com/',
        'retries_before_killing':3,
        'retry_sleep':2
    },
    'live1':{
        'envname':'live1',
        'user':'deploy_user',
        'host':'myapp-live1.com',
        'host_string':'myapp-live1.com',
        'path':'/opt/myapp/live1/',
        'www_root':'http://myapp-live1.com/',
        'retries_before_killing':1,
        'retry_sleep':1
    },
    'live2':{
        'envname':'live2',
        'user':'deploy_user',
        'host':'myapp-live2.com',
        'host_string':'myapp-live2.com',
        'path':'/opt/myapp/live2/',
        'www_root':'http://myapp.com/',
        'retries_before_killing':1,
        'retry_sleep':1
    }
}

TEST_HOSTS = ['test','staging','uat']
LIVE_HOSTS = ['live1','live2']

def test():
    env.update(dict(APP_SERVERS['test']))

def staging():
    env.update(dict(APP_SERVERS['staging']))

def uat():
    env.update(dict(APP_SERVERS['uat']))

def live1():
    env.update(dict(APP_SERVERS['live1']))

def live2():
    env.update(dict(APP_SERVERS['live2']))


#  GROUPS OF SERVERS DEFINITION
def live_servers():
    env['hosts'] = [APP_SERVERS[a]['host'] for a in APP_HOSTS]

def test_servers():
    env['hosts'] = [APP_SERVERS[a]['host'] for a in APP_HOSTS]

def env_update(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        if not len(env.hosts):
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
        else:
            env.update(dict(APP_SERVERS[filter(lambda x: APP_SERVERS[x]['host']==env.host,APP_SERVERS)[0]]))
            func(*args,**kwargs)
    return func_wrapper

@env_update
def pull_commits():
    #some_code
    run('uptime')
```

I have possibility to run group execute task fab live_servers pull_commits and also single fab live1 pull_commits.

I know there could be also something like duplication of tasks with separate servers fab live1 pull_commits live2 pull_commits but I believe that fabric was written for distributed systems which has different paths of apps and users etc.

So my question is: Is there easier way to do it? like something build in to fabric(also roledefs with extra dict keys didn't work for me)? Or am I not seeing some fabric functionality?
I want to keep this simple single/multiple host deployment commands like : fab live_servers pull_commits, fab test pull_commits

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using your current approach, consider just using the `host_string` as the key to the ARG_SERVERS dictionary, and then load information as required inside the tasks (including any required updates to to the fabric environment. Making this adjustment means you should also be able get roles working.

For example:

```
@task
def pull_commits():
    hostinfo = ARG_SERVERS[env.host_string]
    # ... more code
    run(...)
```

One further suggestion is to consider using an ssh config file (~/.ssh/config) to define ssh aliases for all of your machines. This puts all of your host/host_string/username information in a central location, and has the advantage that you can then refer to a host with a single meaningful name and simplifies ARG_SERVERS.

```
# contents of $HOME/.ssh/config
Host test
    HostName myapp-test.com
    User deploy-user

Host staging
    HostName myapp-staging.com
    User deploy-user

Host uat
    HostName myapp-uat.com
    User deploy-user

Host live1
    HostName myapp-live1.com
    User deploy-user

Host live2
    HostName myapp-live2.com
    User deploy-user
```

As per a more traditional fabric task model, you should now be able to do things like:

```
# single host
$ fab -H live1 pull_commits

# multiple hosts
$ fab -H test,staging pull_commits
```

Or roles (as per the fabric documentation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrew but this is not what I wanted. First of all About defining ~/.ssh/config - I don't think it's good Idea because it would have to be done by every developer who want to use fabric and in my situation devs just want to run fabric command and don't care about configuration of their ssh clients, and I dont think its good for future and "central location". I'm concerned about your solution as for example one host details(IP,credentials) change - ALL developers using fabric will have to change their ssh config-  am I right?

Comment: Also I want to use extra configurations parameters for Django and in your solution it's lost. Don't think putting them to ssh config will be good . Summarizing: if I wont use ssh config I cant follow your solution -H -R as it won't work. I also  wanted to have group of hosts (something like roledefs) in one name in big environment -H wont work specifying fab deploy live1,live2...live10 is just more typing which I wanted to avoid.